# grep occurrences after match

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I'm trying to grep the occurrences for 2 scenarios:
1. before the 1st space
2. before the end of the line

Example

```
-Dcatalina.base=/apps/kio/jal/current/mi_loki_porf -Dcatalina.home=/apps/kio/jal/current/mi_loki_porf
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/apps/kio/jal/current/mi_loki_porf/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

1. I wanted to extract the occurences after the word '-Dcatalina.base=' before the 1st space and that would be /apps/kio/jal/current/mi_loki_porf
2. Extract the occurences after the word '-Dcatalina.base' but before the end of line and that would be /apps/kio/jal/current/mi_loki_porf -Dcatalina.home=/apps/kio/jal/current/mi_loki_porf

Also, how should I approach if I've no idea about the occurences after the match, say ocurrences after '-Dcatalina.base=' can be words or alphanumeric or can be only special characters

```
-Dcatalina.base=*(76yhg5)
or -Dcatalina.base=123345
or -Dcatalina.base=hellohowareyou
or -Dcatalina.base= *&^%$
```

What I've tried

```
grep -Po '(?<=-Dcatalina.base=).*' my.log
```

and it gives me the entire match after -Dcatalina.base

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: oh sorry forgot to add that, I 've edited my question.

Comment: Using perl: `perl -nE '/(?<=-Dcatalina\.base=)(\S+)(.*)/ && say $1,"\n",$&' my.log`

Comment: THat worked great, is it possible in grep too ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with grep (or I don't know how!).

Comment: oh okay, thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using perl, you can do:

```
perl -nE '/(?<=-Dcatalina\.base=)(\S+).*/ && say $1,"\n",$&' my.log
```

This will apply the regex on every line of the file `my.log` and print if it matches.

**Explanation:**

```
/                       : regex delimiter
  (?<=                  : positive lookbehind
    -Dcatalina\.base=   : literally
  )                     : end lookbehind
  (\S+)                 : group 1, 1 or more non space
  .*                    : 0 or more any character but newline
/                       : regex delimiter

&&                      : logical and, the following is executed only if the regex matches
say $1,"\n",$&          : print content of group 1, a line break and the whole match
```

**Result for given example:**

```
/apps/kio/jal/current/mi_loki_porf
/apps/kio/jal/current/mi_loki_porf -Dcatalina.home=/apps/kio/jal/current/mi_loki_porf
```